# google sheet api nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

i have data in google sheet fist column is id with every id there are associated data . i want to get multiple rows in one search by using specific id no. for that i want to use batchGetByDataFilter  i dont know how to use because i am new to google sheet . kindly help me .
 async function gsrun(cl){

```
const gsapi=google.sheets({version:'v4',auth:cl}) 
let data = await gsapi.spreadsheets.values.batchGetByDataFilter({ 
  spreadsheetId: '1rRS3jugb-txthDdZ0x0nGSzyLna64mBmKnUVkditeTM',
  range: 'Sheet1!a1:g100'
})       

console.log(data.data.values)
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your situation? 1. In order to use `batchGetByDataFilter` in Sheets API, the metadata is required to be set to the Spreadsheet. How about this? 2. Can I ask you about the result values you expect? 3. Can your `gsapi` be used for retrieving values from the Spreadsheet? Namely, you have confirmed that the authorization process of your script has already been done?

Comment: thank you for responding  .  gsapi is able retrieve data from google sheet but it is collecting entire row and column . but i only want to receive specific data . i have 5 column and lot of rows in my data first row is id ex. 101 and associated row is containing data . and i only want get data by  id . i am using first time google sheet no idea how to use metadata.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I could confirm that you have already done the authorization for retrieving the values from Spreadsheet using Sheets API. But from `i only want get data by id`, I cannot understand about the result values you expect. What values do you want to retrieve by searching the ID from the column "A"? I think that I might be able to propose the solution by correctly understainding your goal.

Comment: thanks for your quick response . i have data with  header name in  1st  row : i d  ,product , price , quantity . in 2nd row i have data 101 , lime ,45 ,1  and also till 100 row . i want to get data  row by using id

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your case, you want to retrieve the rows by searching the ID from the column "A". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes sir  i want same please help me out and also let me know how to use this filter function .

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the rows by searching an ID at the column "A" using Node.js.
- In your script, you have already done the authorization process for retrieving the values from Spreadsheet.

For this, how about this answer?

In this case, I would like to propose to use the query language instead of `batchGetByDataFilter`. By this, the searched rows can be directly retrieved by the query language. I thought that this method is simpler. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

In this script, the access token is used from `cl` of `const gsapi=google.sheets({version:'v4',auth:cl})`. In this case, the modules of `request` and `csv-parse` are used.

```
const request = require("request");
const csvParse = require("csv-parse");

const spreadsheetId = "###";  // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
const sheetId = "###";  // Please set the sheet ID.
const searchId = "###";  // Please set the search ID.

cl.getRequestHeaders().then((authorization) => {
  const query = `select * where A='${searchId}'`;
  const url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${spreadsheetId}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&gid=${sheetId}&tq=${encodeURI(query)}`;
  let options = {
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    headers: authorization,
  };
  request(options, (err, res, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    csvParse(result, {}, (err, ar) => console.log(ar));
  });
});
```

#### References:

- [Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)
- [Spreadsheet ID](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#spreadsheet_id)
- [Sheet ID](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#sheet_id)

Comment: sorry for delay in response please let me know witch button need to press

Comment: @brownveg Could you understand about my replying?